# Converting EML (MIME) to MSG with python

Tags: python, mime, win32com, mapi, msg

I'm trying to convert EML file to MSG (Outlook) file using python. Using various examples I was able to gather this code, but well, it doesn't work. It creates a msg file but the file is unreadable by Outlook and the size is two times bigger than the input eml file. I'm a little bit lost, any ideas?

```
from win32com.mapi import mapi
from win32com.mapi import mapitags
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
from win32com import storagecon

import ctypes
import platform
import winreg
import uuid 
import sys
import os

mapi.MAPIInitialize((mapi.MAPI_INIT_VERSION, mapi.MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS))

IconvOLE = ctypes.OleDLL(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLMIME.DLL')
clsid_class = uuid.UUID(str(mapi.CLSID_IConverterSession)).bytes_le
iclassfactory = uuid.UUID(str(pythoncom.IID_IClassFactory)).bytes_le
com_classfactory = ctypes.c_long(0)
IconvOLE.DllGetClassObject(clsid_class, iclassfactory, ctypes.byref(com_classfactory))
MyFactory = pythoncom.ObjectFromAddress(com_classfactory.value, pythoncom.IID_IClassFactory)
cs =  MyFactory.CreateInstance (None, str(mapi.IID_IConverterSession))

eml = mapi.OpenStreamOnFileW(r"C:\test.eml")

stg = pythoncom.StgCreateDocfile(r"C:\test.msg",
    storagecon.STGM_CREATE | storagecon.STGM_READWRITE | storagecon.STGM_TRANSACTED)

msg = mapi.OpenIMsgOnIStg(0, None, stg, None, 0, mapi.MAPI_UNICODE)

cs.MIMEToMAPI(eml, msg, win32com.mapi.mapi.CCSF_SMTP | win32com.mapi.mapi.CCSF_INCLUDE_BCC)

msg.SaveChanges(0)

mapi.MAPIUninitialize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it started to work after I have moved from Outlook x86 to x64, and I added the following registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4E3A7680-B77A-11D0-9DA5-00C04FD65685}]
@="CLSID_IConverterSession"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4E3A7680-B77A-11D0-9DA5-00C04FD65685}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLMIME.DLL"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{9EADBD1A-447B-4240-A9DD-73FE7C53A981}]
@="CLSID_IMimeMessage"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{9EADBD1A-447B-4240-A9DD-73FE7C53A981}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLMIME.DLL"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{9EADBD1A-447B-4240-A9DD-73FE7C53A981}\Typelib]
@="{9EADBD25-447B-4240-A9DD-73FE7C53A981}"
```

Keys are copies of the keys that you can find in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID
```

Working code:

```
mapi.MAPIInitialize((mapi.MAPI_INIT_VERSION, mapi.MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS))


inf = mapi.OpenStreamOnFile(r"C:\Users\xxx\raw.eml")

stg = pythoncom.StgCreateDocfile(r"C:\Users\xxx\raw.msg",
    storagecon.STGM_CREATE | storagecon.STGM_READWRITE | storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | storagecon.STGM_TRANSACTED)

msg = mapi.OpenIMsgOnIStg(0, None, stg, None, 0, mapi.MAPI_UNICODE)

cs = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(mapi.CLSID_IConverterSession, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, mapi.IID_IConverterSession)


cs.MIMEToMAPI(inf, msg, 0)

msg.SaveChanges(0)

mapi.MAPIUninitialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sizes don't matter, especially if you compare different file formats.
Secondly, try to open the MSG file in a utility like [SSView](https://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html) (it shows the data on the `IStorage` level) or [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click OpenIMsgOnIStg button) - it will show the MSG file data on the MAPI level.

Perhaps most importantly, as of Outlook 2016, [IConverterSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iconvertersessioniunknown) interface only works if your code is running inside the outlook.exe address space (i.e. your code is a COM/VSTO addin or Outlook VBA). Also, your code never checks that `IConverterSession::MIMEToMAPI` returns a success return code.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), it allows to convert an EML file to MSG without using Outlook converter as easily as (in VB script):

```vb
    set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT 'not required
    set Msg = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\test.msg")
    Msg.Sent = true
    Msg.Import "c:\temp\test.eml", 1024 '1024 is olRfc822
    Msg.Save
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I know about Redemption. I wanted to resolve this issue on my own. I was thinking that maybe I missing some essential steps or some steps are just wrong. The msg file is created but it looks that the whole content of the source eml file is put in the PR_BODY_W property tag, all headers and everything.

Comment: Are you sure there are no line breaks in the header? Can Outlook itself open the EML file?

Comment: The EML file is fine. It is exported from web outlook and I can open it in the Outlook app. The content part of the eml file is utf-8, encoded in base64 and the mail contains some attachments.

Comment: Does the conversion work in OutlookSpy (click IConverterSession | MIMEToMAPI)?

Comment: When I installed Outlook x64 and added some registry keys, it started to work.

Comment: Which registry keys?

Comment: Take a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518310/11268606